# Как удалить все файлы с amazon s3 с помощью jenkins перед копированием артефактов?

Tags: развертывание, jenkins, amazon-web-services, devops

Пытаюсь понять как удалить все файлы с amazon s3 bucket с помощью jenkins перед копированием артифактов в amazon s3 bucket.

Само копирование проходит нормально. Собираю react приложение и содержимое dist забрасываю на amazon s3 bucket. Делаю всё это c помощью jenkins который крутится на es2.

Проблема заключается в том, что все файлы в dist подписываются разным хешем после каждой новой сборки и забрасываются на amazon s3 bucket и сам bucket превращается в свалку. Хотел его очищать перед тем как забрасывать новые файлы.

Для копирования использую: publish artifacts to S3 Bucket - плагин

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил утилиту aws на хост где крутится jenkins и делаю так

```
aws s3 rm s3://<адрес вашего бакета> --recursive
```

Answer (score 2):

aws s3 rb s3://bucket-name --force
Источник: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/delete-or-empty-bucket.html#delete-bucket-awscli